# Could not read/write from/to remote repository

Tags: github, ssh, https, ssh-keys, git-push

I am getting that error when I tried to push commits to Github:

```
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/...../...../': 
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Also there are similar errors you may get for the same reaon. For example:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in `/Users/username/Documents/cakebook/.git/`
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And so on..

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem follow these steps (If you are trying to clone repository as HTTPS or you already cloned HTTPS and trying to push the changes to the Github):

1-) `git remote -v`
run this command on terminal and you'll see something like that:

```
origin    https://github.com/career-karma-tutorials/ck-git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/career-karma-tutorials/ck-git (push)
```

2-) `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:career-karma-tutorials/ck-git` then run this. You'll write your github repo instead of `career-karma-tutorials/ck-git`

We are doing this because we will use SSH instead of HTTPS for cloning the repository.

3-)`ssh-keygen` then run this. You will see these:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\asasa/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\asasa/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
```

Just press enter for all these (You can do this security stuff if you want but I am skipping it)

Then you'll see an image like this:

```
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3542]----+
|     =*--B.      |
|    o+=-=++.     |
|    o.+---o.     |
|   . o.+= o.     |
|    ..= S=.      |
|    *+ -o. . .   |
|    .o+.    . E  |
|   ..*       .   |
|    +.*          |
+----[SHA126]-----+
```

4-) `cat C:\Users\asasa/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.` Then you will run this. (""C:\Users\asasa/.ssh/id_rsa.pub."" this part is same with the one in the 3th step)

After run this you'll see a huge text (that's your key). Copy it and go to Github/settings/keys press new SSH key and paste your key in key section.

Then go back to terminal and make your push or clone. It will work!:)